# Is it possible to convert typescript interface keys to javascript array in react native?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do this in react-native:

```
import { keys } from "ts-transformer-keys";

interface Props {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
const keysOfProps = keys<Props>();

console.log(keysOfProps);
```

but there's no support for babel compile with it:

https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys#how-to-use-the-custom-transformer

is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around may be to use a JavaScript object to create the Type and keys:

```js
const PropsObj = {
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  age: 0
}

type Props = typeof PropsObj

const keyOfProps = Object.keys(PropsObj) as (keyof Props)[]
```